# ClassNotFoundException が解決出来ません

Tags: java, tomcat

サーバー起動時にClassNotFoundExceptionが出力され、解決出来ません。
エラー内容は以下です。

```
重大: フィルタ Encoding の起動中の例外です
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.fnavi.bww.com.filter.EncodingFilter
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1313)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:520)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4574)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5193)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

確認した内容としては、

- net.test.bww.com.filter内にEncodingFilter.classが存在する
- web.xml設定

```xml
  <filter>
    <filter-name>Encoding</filter-name>
    <filter-class>net.test.bww.com.filter.EncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>Windows-31J</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
```

- tomcatライブラリー内に、EncodingFilter.javaを含むjarが存在する
  （webライブラリーにも配置）
- クラス名は間違えていません

という感じです。
解決方法の分かる方がいましたら、ご教授をお願いします。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tomcatライブラリー(おそらくtomcatのディレクトリ/libのことでしょうか)の中、ないしはWebアプリケーションのwarファイル構成/WEB-INF/lib の中に配置したjarファイルに、上記 EncodingFilter.class が含まれているのは間違いないでしょうか。

おそらく記述ミスだと思うのですが、.javaファイルではなく、.classファイルであっていますよね。

jarファイルの中身を確認する方法としては、jarファイルはzipで解凍できますので、拡張子をzipに変換して解凍すると確認できます。解凍後、上記EncodingFilterが、/net/test/bww/com/filter/ ディレクトリに存在していることも確認してください。

hata 様もご指摘のとおり、スタックトレースに出ているパッケージ名が異なっておりますので、jarファイルを作成したときのパッケージ名と、実際にソースをコンパイルしたときのパッケージ名が変わってしまっていないかも確認が必要です。

なお、余談ですが、Tomcatのlibと、WebアプリケーションのWEB-INF/lib 両方に入れる必要はありません。複数のWebアプリケーションで共通したものを使うのでなければ、Tomcatのlibには含めません。

Comment: jarファイルの中身を確認したところ、EncodingFilter.classがありませんでした。
なので、jarを手動でtomcatライブラリの中に配置したところ、エラーが解消されました。

なぜ、EncodingFilter.classが無かったのかは分かっていませんが、解決することが出来ました。あ

また、ライブラリの構成についてもご指摘に従って、構成しなおします。
ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2):

エラーメッセージでは、パッケージ名は、`net.test.bww.com.filter`ではなく、`net.fnavi.gw.com.filter`となっていますが、`import`などでの指定で問題があるのではないでしょうか？

Comment: すいません、パッケージ名は記述ミスです